# How to write a divide function that produces 0 if the divisor is 0?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

If it tries to divide with 0, the function result should be 0.

```
  org 100h
  mov al,b
  mov bl,c
  mov cl,0
  cmp bl,cl
  jmp posht;
  div bl
  mov ah,d
  mul ah
  mov ah,a
  sub ah,al
posht:
  mov al,0
  ret

a dw 10
b dw 8
c dw 4
d dw 2
zero dw 0
```

How can I make this code work on assembly language emu8086?

Comment: Check if the divisor is 0 and if yes, return 0 instead of dividing.

Comment: org  100h 

mov al,b
mov bl,c 
mov cl,0
cmp bl,cl 

jmp posht;

div bl 

mov ah,d
mul ah
mov ah,a
sub ah,al
 
posht: mov al,0
  

   
ret   

a dw 10
b dw 8
c dw 4
d dw 2
zero dw 0
Like this?

Comment: Posting an entire program in a comment makes it unreadable. Why don't you just try it and see if it works?

Comment: Sorry I'm new on this language and I'm not very sure,but I think it's working thanks

Comment: @TheHamshah If you have new code, please add the code to your question.  Comments are not really suitable for this.

Comment: `jmp posht` is an unconditional jump, that's obviously wrong because it *always* jumps.  Use `test cl,cl` or `cmp cl, 0` and `jnz`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> mov bl,c
> mov cl,0
> cmp bl,cl
> jmp posht
> ```

To actually bail out if the divisor happens to be 0, you need to change this unconditional `jmp` into a conditional one: `je` (jump if equal).

Before you can do the (by now allowed) division, you still need to empty the `AH` register since the `div bl` instruction will divide the whole of `AX`, not just `AL`.

You need to re-think how your function reports its result. For now, regardless of the divisor being zero or not, `AL` will always report back being equal to 0. **How will you make the distinction?**

```
  mov ax, b    ; 8 Also defines AH
  mov bl, c    ; 4
  cmp bl, 0
  je  posht    ; Bail out on zero divisor
  div bl       ; 8 / 4 --> AL=2 AH=0
  mov ah, d    ; 2
  mul ah       ; 2 * 2 --> AX=4
  mov ah, a    ; 10
  sub ah, al   ; 10 - 4 --> AH=6
  ...          ; ?
  RET
posht:
  mov al, 0
  ret
```

Comment: org  100h 

mov al,b
mov bl,c 
cmp bl,0
je posht:

div bl 

mov ah,d
mul ah
mov ah,a
sub ah,al
 

posht: mov al,0  

   
ret   

a dw 20
b dw 8
c dw 4
d dw 4

This is how I made it after some edits,so it's okay now?

Comment: @TheHamshah It's not okay.  First reread Sep's 2nd paragraph about using `AX` instead of `AL`. Then see how Sep's code has 2 `RET` instructions.